# how to pause my loop if it reaches the bottom? Window.requestanimationframe - Javascript/html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's my full code, if you want to run it. 
https://repl.it/FEl8/0
Here's just the javascript :

```
    window.onload   =   function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var warrior = document.getElementById('warrior');
    var enemyxpos = 100;
    var enemyypos = 75;
    canvas.width = window.screen.width;
    canvas.height = window.screen.height;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "sprite_guy_warrior-1.png";

     window.requestAnimationFrame(function loop(){
          enemyypos +=1;
          ctx.clearRect(enemyxpos,enemyypos,90,90);
          ctx.drawImage(image,enemyxpos,enemyypos,90,90);
         window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      });
 };
```

I want to stop 'image' when it gets to the bottom of the canvas. Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Comment: `if(enemyypos + 90 < canvas.height){  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}`

Comment: you need to change the subject in the case of start again.

Answer (score 0):

get the `height of the canvas` and check against the value of `y`.

```
   window.onload   =   function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
     var cheight=canvas.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var warrior = document.getElementById('warrior');
    var enemyxpos = 100;
    var enemyypos = 75;
    var flag=90;//height of the image
    canvas.width = window.screen.width;
    canvas.height = window.screen.height;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "http://cliparts.co/cliparts/nrc/L6p/nrcL6pi84.png";
     window.requestAnimationFrame(function loop(){
          enemyypos +=1;
          ctx.clearRect(enemyxpos,enemyypos,90,90);
          ctx.drawImage(image,enemyxpos,enemyypos,90,90);
          if(cheight+flag >= enemyypos){ //here...........
             window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
          }else{
               ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//clear the canvas ans start again.
             enemyypos = 75; 
          window.requestAnimationFrame(loop); }
      });

};
```

[DEOM HERE](https://repl.it/FEl8/22)

Comment: `flag` should be drawn `image` height : 90.

Comment: @Kaiido i guess it is stopping some what before. Initialy i thought of taking the start value of y.

Comment: Well the question states *I want to stop 'image' when it gets to the bottom of the canvas*. We can arguably determine that 'image' gets to the bottom when its own bottom reaches the canvas one. Since you draw it at a height of 90, `flag` should be 90.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this condition in your loop:

```
if (enemyypos <= canvas.height - 90){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Here is [repl](https://repl.it/FEl8/17)

Comment: Thanks, how would you suggest going about pausing the loop. Like if I wanted to pause the loop when the 'image' gets to the bottom, then send it back to the top

Comment: @Moe Chunghtai, like this?

`if (enemyypos <= canvas.height - 90){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
} else {
    ctx.clearRect(enemyxpos,enemyypos,90,90);
    ctx.drawImage(image,enemyxpos,75,90,90);
}`

Comment: actually I meant like get to the bottom and start heading towards the top from the bottom (sort of like a ball falling down, and then bouncing back up)